# How to configure the "Resume Program" button in debugger mode?

Tags: intellij-idea

When debugging, I often need to use the "Resume Program" option. The easiest way to access this is through the "Console" view, as shown in the screenshot. However, currently on the Console, there are only 'Step Over/into/force step into/out', there is no "Resume Program" option. How can I make it appear on the Console too so that I can click conveniently, just as other debugging options. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you attach full Debug tool window screenshot? Resume button is located in [Debug toolbar](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debug-tool-window.html) on the left side: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6chtx5rfbaok6vi/ResumeDebug.png?dl=0

Comment: @Andrey, that's great to know. It's right there!